# How to test subclass of tornado.web.RequestHandler without using AsyncTestCase or AsyncHTTPTestCase (since they're deprecated)?

Tags: python, unit-testing, tornado

I've got a subclass of `tornado.web.RequestHandler`, but the common test-cases are deprecated as of 6.2. Most resources I've found (including many questions on StackOverflow) use the deprecated classes, which I would like to avoid.

Tornado's documentation says to use `unittest.IsolatedAsyncToTestCase` instead, but without much of an indication as to how to actually do that. Furthermore—I think I'd like to simply instantiate my RequestHandler to directly test its methods w.o. relying on a TestCase class, but am having a hard time doing that.

So I have a couple of additional questions besides that in the title:

1. `tornado.web.RequestHandler` typically needs an `Application` and a `Request` to be instantiated, but when I provide them, I recieve a `HTTPRequest' object has no attribute 'supports_http_1_1'` error. Both my request and application are pretty straightforward:

   ```
   application = tornado.web.Application([
       (r"/", tornado.web.RequestHandler)
   ])
   request = tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest(method="POST", url="/", headers=None, body=None)
   ```

   I attempt to instantiate w/ `tornado.web.RequestHandler(application, request)`.
2. How can I use `unittest.IsolatedAsyncToTestCase` and why would I need to?

Comment: Did you consider pytest-tornado? It simplify things like creating app for tests... https://pypi.org/project/pytest-tornado/

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncTestCase` and `AsyncHTTPTestCase` are no longer deprecated. See [Pull Request #3223](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/pull/3223) for full discussion and reverted changes.

Although there are still a few methods on these classes which are deprecated. I suggest reading the [latest version of the docs](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/latest/testing.html) which is like a preview for the upcoming version 6.3.